# How to create a timer function?

Tags: java, function, timer

I have a `func a(x, y z)` that would like to time, is there a way to this:

`time = timeit( a(x,y,z) )` in java, time it would accept any func.

like:

```
long timeit(Object func){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    func(...);
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Comment: Either through reflection or Command pattern. Or use a scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Reflection:

If `functionCall()` is an instance method
-> create an object for the class
-> Invoke method using object of that class

```
MyClass objToPass = new MyClass();
Method m;
//Assuming functionCall() takes no arguments
m = MyClass.class.getMethod("functionCall", new Class[]{});
//Parameter list empty
m.invoke(objToPass, new Object[]{});
```

Answer (score 5):

You need place your function in `Runnable` interface, in `public void run()` method.
Modified code:

```
public long timeit(Runnable func)
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    func.run();
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Function:

```
public class MyFunction implements Runnable
{
    @Override public void run() { System.out.println(); }
}
```

Comment: I see, this would only work for functions implemented in this way.

Comment: Yes. Because Java can't pass function as argument like in JavaScript.

Comment: @AndreyRedov You can pass a `Method` object and call it via reflection

Comment: Yes, but the `Runnable` is better as it quicker and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining an interface (let's say FunctionRunner) with just one method (let's call it run()). Now you can implement this interface and do whatever you want to do when run() is being called. Then your Code to measure the time of a function would be like this:

```
long timeit(FunctionRunner func){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    func.run();
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Comment: Than this post differs from mine?

Comment: @Andrey: Not much, but I was faster :b ... but your solution is actually nicer, because you use Runnable, which is an existing interface